# Passing Parameter to javascript/JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I am using a function of JS/JQ to convert values into currency (i.e. add commas).
It's working fine but I am not able to give a parameter to this function.
Please help me to pass parameters to this function.

```
function VTC() {
    var n = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var number = n.toString(), 
    dollars = number.split('.')[0], 
    cents = (number.split('.')[1] || '') +'00';
    dollars = dollars.split('').reverse().join('')
        .replace(/(\d{3}(?!$))/g, '$1,')
        .split('').reverse().join('');
    return dollars + '.' + cents.slice(0, 2);
}
```

The second function which calls this function is

```
function f1() {
    var res = VTC($().val()); 
    document.getElementById("text2").value = res ;
}
```

I want to pass a parameter like 200900. At this moment, it's getting the value from a field and it's working fine but I want to pass this value as a parameter.

Comment: Have you seen your function definition? I think youll spot your error

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6a0971s1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move case-specific things out of your `VTC` function and into the `f1` helper function. If you do this, you can restructure you code by making `VTC` accept a number as a parameter:

```
function VTC(n) {
    var number = n.toString(), 
    dollars = number.split('.')[0], 
    cents = (number.split('.')[1] || '') +'00';
    dollars = dollars.split('').reverse().join('')
        .replace(/(\d{3}(?!$))/g, '$1,')
        .split('').reverse().join('');
    return dollars + '.' + cents.slice(0, 2);
}
```

Then, move the `getElementById` call to your helper function and then pass the number to the other function.

```
function f1() 
{
    var num = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var res = VTC(num); 
    document.getElementById("text2").value = res ;
}
```

Now, you can call `VTC` with any number, and it will work as expected:

```
VTC(2000); // => "2,000.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
function VTC(text2) { //receiving with text2
}


function f1() 
{
  var res = VTC($('#ID').val()); //this is sending the items
  document.getElementById("text2").value = res ;
}
```

Comment: i have some variables in the so i want to pass those variables, #cracker

Comment: pass it with comma and take new var to that function with each

Comment: one more thing you can do is the global variable at the start of the script that will allow you to assign and use that within the script